# Get screen resolution results type mismatch

Tags: vbscript, screen-resolution, hta

I have a HTA file where I resize the window so it will be paced at the right side of the screen.

At some of the computers ( about 10 out of 120) I get the type mismatch error at the line where we want t user the resolution (move or size the window). I take the value I get is not an integer or maybe it is nothing.

All the PCs are on Win 7 and I do not see any difference between them ( however there is it seems)

this is done during the "Window_onLoad" sub:

```
Sub Window_onLoad()
    Dim per
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set getOSVersion = wshShell.Exec("%comspec% /c ver")
    version = getOSVersion.StdOut.ReadAll
    Select Case True
        Case InStr(version, "n 5.") > 1 : GetOS = "XP"
            'WIN XP CODE HERE...
        Case InStr(version, "n 6.") > 1 : GetOS = "Vista/7"
            '<--- Win 7
            strComputer = "."
            Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
            Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_DesktopMonitor")
            For Each objItem In colItems
                intHorizontal = objItem.ScreenWidth
                intVertical = objItem.ScreenHeight
            Next
```

At this point we get the resolution as integers and works fine in 99% of the cases.

If we do not get back Resolution, we try another way get the resolution of 1st screen.

```
If IsNumeric(intHorizontal) And IsNumeric(intVertical) Then
Else
    MsgBox "2"
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_DesktopMonitor where DeviceID = 'DesktopMonitor1'",,0)
    For Each objItem In colItems
        intHorizontal = objItem.ScreenWidth
        intVertical = objItem.ScreenHeight
    Next

    If IsNumeric(intHorizontal) And IsNumeric(intVertical) Then
```

And here we try a 3rd way.

```
    Else
        MsgBox "3"
        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_DesktopMonitor where DeviceID = 'DesktopMonitor2'",,0)
        For Each objItem In colItems
            intHorizontal = objItem.ScreenWidth
            intVertical = objItem.ScreenHeight
        Next
    End If
End If
```

Here we should have the resolution, and we just calculate the correct position.

```
            intLeft = intHorizontal - 300 ' (intHorizontal + 800)/ 2
            intTop = 1 ' (intVertical + 400) / 4
            Window.resizeTo 300, intVertical - 40  '<--- HERE we get the error
            Window.moveTo intLeft, intTop
            'Some additional code here...
        Case InStr(version, "n 10.") > 1 : GetOS = "W10"
            'WIN 10 code here ...
        Case Else : GetOS = "Unknown"
            MsgBox "Not Supported ( Unknown OS)"
    End Select

    'Some addtitonal code here...
End Sub
```

Do you have any idea what can be the problem. Why do I get error at all?

#

As Ansgar Wiechers advised I runed a simple vbs on the PC where I have the issue:

```
msgbox "TEST"
strComputer = "."
                set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
                set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_DesktopMonitor")
        For Each objItem In colItems
                    intHorizontal = objItem.ScreenWidth
                    intVertical = objItem.ScreenHeight
                Next
        msgbox TypeName(intHorizontal)
        msgbox TypeName(intVertical)
        msgbox (intHorizontal)
        msgbox (intVertical)
```

I got:
TEST/
Null/
Null/
error: Invalid use of `intHorizontal`/

Comment: Check the type and value of the variable(s) used at the point where you're getting that error. Then check where the problematic value came from.

Comment: When it works the type if "intHorizontal" and "intVertical" is Long and the value is the resolution. I will check what do I get when the error occurs. At those cases I can not write out the value with msgbox as i get type mismatch again. But I will check the type and get back

Comment: You can try at least `MsgBox TypeName(intHorizontal)`.

Comment: I get the type: Null

Comment: Then the properties of the WMI result didn't have a value. Is that problem temporary, or can you reproduce it on those particular computers? Try with a plain VBScript that just runs the WMI query.

Comment: At the moment I have access to 2 PCs where we have the same issue, while a dozens of others do not have this issue. 
This 2 PC had this issue last week as well, so the PC has been restarted since than. However the users are the same. I will try a plain VBscript as you suggested.

Comment: I did as you advised, I got the same results. Null, Null, invalid use of intHorizontal.  (Editied the original post as well)

Comment: I just tried:      Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_VideoController")  as well, but I had the same issue.

Comment: Is it possible your query returns more then one object? One regular and another with null values? Put the debug statements in the for loop to find out. (I would at least add an `exit for` in your foreach loop if you expect only one result)

Comment: I am afraid I had only one object, which is null. For now I will filter these cases, set a fix size and position for the window and make the window resize able and replaceable for these users. Thank you very much for the effort guys.